# Python max_minus_min_abs

Tags: python

```
def max_minus_min_abs(first_num, second_num):
    return max(first_num, second_num) - min(first_num, second_num)
    print(max_minus_min_abs(15, 4))
```

What am I doing wrong here? It's not printing a number at all.

```
def max_minus_min_abs(first_num, second_num):
    return max(first_num, second_num) - min(first_num, second_num)
    print(max_minus_min_abs(15, 4))
```

I also tried enter numbers where it says return max.

Comment: Did you mean to have the line with `print` *outside* the function?

Comment: What is the difference between the first and the second code snippet?

Comment: The first line of code inside the function is a `return` statement, which terminates the function immediately.  Therefore the `print` statement is never executed...

Comment: Also, since the _call_ to the function is _inside the function itself_, the function is never _called_...

Comment: Honestly, I am struggling a lot in this class. Does print and return do two separate things?
My class is set up where they teach you stuff and then you do assignments, and they have nothing to do with each other so its basically on me to learn, which I can do but I feel lost.

Comment: Did they teach you about indentation in Python?

Comment: _Does print and return do two separate things?_ Yes.  `print()` displays something on the screen, and `return` ends the function and returns a value to whatever other code called the function.

Comment: I adjusted to the following

def max_minus_min_abs(first_num, second_num):
    return max([first_num, second_num]) - min([first_num, second_num])

print(max_minus_min_abs(15, 4))

[RULE] The `circle_area_exact` function should return the expected values to the provided testing input.
[RESULT] FAILED (0/1)
[FEEDBACK] Given 29.873313813033235 as input argument, your implementation of `circle_area_exact` returns a value of
| type NoneType whereas float is expected.

Comment: Maybe the basics of Python can help you, https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_syntax.asp

Answer (score -2, accepted):

One reason is because you need to take the max and min of a list, so you would want to do something like this

```
def max_minus_min_abs(first_num, second_num):
    return max([first_num, second_num]) - min([first_num, second_num])

print(max_minus_min_abs(15, 4))
```

Comment: And there it is. Thats what I was doing wrong. I feel so silly.

Comment: That was not the reason. You changed something else which you didn't mention.

Comment: Can I ask another question, what is the difference between:
return max([first_num, second_num]) - min([first_num, second_num]) 
and return max(first_num, second_num) - min(first_num, second_num)

Comment: The problem was the indention of the `print` rather than the iterable

Comment: mkrieger, not sure what it could have been, I entered in 
def max_minus_min_abs(first_num, second_num):
    return max(first_num, second_num) - min(first_num, second_num)
    
print(max_minus_min_abs(5,4)) 
and It came back as 1

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not print any number because of the indention of the `print` statement.
In your code snippet the print is indented as much as the `return` which means the print is inside the function itself, whereas the print should be outside of the function.

```
def max_minus_min_abs(first_num, second_num):
    return max(first_num, second_num) - min(first_num, second_num)
print(max_minus_min_abs(15, 4))
```

[You can read here more about indention](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/indentation-in-python/)

Answer (score 0):

All fine, but print code is incorrect.
The problem is that you have placed the print statement inside the function after the return statement. In Python, when a return statement is executed, the function immediately exits, and any code after it is not executed.

```
def max_minus_min_abs(first_num, second_num):
    result = max(first_num, second_num) - min(first_num, second_num)
    return result

# Now call the function and print the result
print(max_minus_min_abs(15, 4))
```

The result is `11`.

`max([first_num, second_num]))` vs `max(first_num, second_num)`

1. max([first_num, second_num])), you are passing a single list [first_num, second_num] as the argument to max function.
2. max(first_num, second_num), you are directly passing two separate arguments, first_num and second_num, to the max function.

In summary, both versions of the code achieve the same result, which is to calculate the absolute difference between first_num and second_num. The difference is in how the values are passed to the max and min functions, but the outcome is identical. Most programmers prefer the second version (return max(first_num, second_num) - min(first_num, second_num)) because it's more concise and easier to read.

Comment: Why create the `result` variable and then immediately return it?  Just return the value of `max()` directly.